# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable for loop

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, minecraft, iterable

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

big_img_path = 'bloodredboy.jpg'
resolution = 0.05
small_img_path = 'Minecraft'

def LoadImages():
    global small_img_path

imagelist = list(os.walk(small_img_path))[0][2]
images = {}
for im in imagelist:
    img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\VVA\Desktop\\'+small_img_path+'\\'+im)
    r = 0
    g = 0
    b = 0
    count = 0
    for y in img:
        for x in y:
            r += x[0]
            g += x[1]
            b += x[2]
            count += 1
    r /= count
    b /= count
    g /= count
    images[r'C:\Users\VVA\Videos\Desktop\\'+small_img_path+'\\'+im] = [r, g, b]

return images

def change_resolution(img, resolution):
    res = []
    height = len(img)
    width = len(img[0])

yy = 0
for y in range(0, height, round(1/resolution)):
    yy += 1
    xx = 0
    res.append([])
    for x in range(0, width, round(1/resolution)):
        res[yy-1].append(img[y][x])
        xx += 1

return np.array(res)

def ask_block(rgb):
    global images

    record_block = None
    record_value = 99999999999999
    for image in images.items():
        r = abs(rgb[0] - image[1][0])
        g = abs(rgb[1] - image[1][1])
        b = abs(rgb[2] - image[1][2])
        if r+g+b < record_value:
            record_block = image[0]
            record_value = r+g+b

    return record_block

def make_img_out_of_blocks(img):
    count = 0
    total = len(img) * len(img[0])
    rows = []
    yy = 0
    for y in img:
        yy += 1
        xx = 0
        row = []
        for x in y:
            block = ask_block(x)
            block = cv2.imread(block)
            try:
                row = np.concatenate((row, block), axis=1)
            except:
                row = block
             xx += 1
            count += 1
        rows.append(row)
        print(f'{round(count/total*100, 2)}% Completed')
    for row in rows:
        try:
            res = np.concatenate((res, row), axis=0)
        except:
            res = row

    return res


print('Loading Images...')
images = LoadImages()
img = cv2.imread(big_img_path)
print('Done')
if resolution != 1:
    print('Changing resolution...')
    img = change_resolution(img, resolution)
    print('Done')
print('Transforming to Blocks...')
img = make_img_out_of_blocks(img)
print('Done')
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)
cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and this is the error:
I tried to change the file path file name folder images
but no progress.
As you can see i am using numpy and cv2

Loading Images...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\VVA\Desktop\Image_out_of_Minecraft_Blocks.py", line 94, in 
images = LoadImages()
File "C:\Users\VVA\Desktop\Image_out_of_Minecraft_Blocks.py", line 20, in LoadImages
for y in img:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Make sure the image path is correct. I'd recommend using `os.path.join()`

Comment: Print this to see exactly what it is trying to load.
`'C:\Users\VVA\Desktop\\'+small_img_path+'\\'+im`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter If i am using os.path.join it is giving me this error
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Keri It is giving me this error
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'im' referenced before assignment

Comment: Are you printing this after the line `for im in imagelist`?

Comment: It is solved now my minecraft folder got corrupted.